# NSWindow does not become active/key when activating the app

Tags: macos, nswindow

I have a single window Mac OSX app.  The user can click 'x' (windowShouldClose() fires) and then I will just order the window back (ie, not exit the app).

If I try to bring the app back by clicking it from the dock or via cmd-tab, it doesn't become active.

I'm assuming I need to explicitly make the window key/active when it's clicked from the doc.

If so, what's the message sent to the app once the user clicks on the app from the dock?

Answer (score 0):

You should inherit from NSWindowController like this:

```
class MyWindowController: NSWindowController, NSWindowDelegate {

    func windowShouldClose(_ sender: NSWindow) -> Bool {
        NSApp.hide(nil)
        return false
    }
}
```

Then you need just open your Main (or whatever name you have) storyboard, choose Window Controller and set your MyWindowController to it:

[image]

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54530275/4519527)

Answer (score -1):

Add these methods to the application delegate:

```
- (BOOL) applicationShouldOpenUntitledFile: (NSApplication *) sender {
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL) applicationOpenUntitledFile: (NSApplication *) theApplication {
    // Reopen your window here
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't change any behavior unfortunately.