# Show and hide window instead of terminating app on close click in cocoa app

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa

I have been trying to show hide window on close(red button) click on the window. I would like to do is hide the window and when a user clicks on my app again it will show again.

Thanks in advance to all the developers who provide an answer. I am new to Cocoa apps. I am iOS developers so I have not much knowledge about cocoa apps.

I tried to hide(*:) method and orderOut(*:) method too. but not working.

```
class ViewController : NSViewController, NSWindowDelegates {

    override func viewDidAppear() {
         self.view.window?.delegate = self
    }

    func windowShouldClose(_ sender: NSWindow) -> Bool {
         //NSApplication.shared.terminate(self)
         //NSApp.hide(self)
         //self.view.window?.orderOut(sender)
        return false
    }
}
```

I want to create a timer app which runs in the background if user click on close it will hide instead of terminating. and when he clicks again from dock menu it will reopen the window.

Comment: Have you considered simply setting the window's `hidesOnDeactivate` property instead of managing it yourself? And then, perhaps, either make the window non-closable or return true from the app delegate's `applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed(_:)` method?

Comment: @KenThomases I did not try that but I will consider that and try it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I have found solution. Thanks to @Silvester suggestion to present NSViewController.
On button click event :

```
@IBAction func onButtonClick(_ sender: VSButton) {
    let animator = ReplacePresentationAnimator()
    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateController(withIdentifier: "identifier") as! yourVC
    present(vc, animator: animator) 
}
```

Custom animator class :

```
  class ReplacePresentationAnimator: NSObject, NSViewControllerPresentationAnimator {

        func animatePresentation(of viewController: NSViewController, from fromViewController: NSViewController) {
            if let window = fromViewController.view.window {
                NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup({ (context) -> Void in
                fromViewController.view.animator().alphaValue = 0
            }, completionHandler: { () -> Void in
                viewController.view.alphaValue = 0
                window.contentViewController = viewController
                viewController.view.animator().alphaValue = 1.0
                })
            }
        }

        func animateDismissal(of viewController: NSViewController, from fromViewController: NSViewController) {
            if let window = viewController.view.window {
                NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup({ (context) -> Void in
                viewController.view.animator().alphaValue = 0
            }, completionHandler: { () -> Void in
                fromViewController.view.alphaValue = 0
                window.contentViewController = fromViewController
                fromViewController.view.animator().alphaValue = 1.0
                })
            }
        }
    }
```

This will work perfectly with Silvester MyWindowController. Thank you.

Answer (score 12):

I'm not much into Mac OS development, but I think you should inherit from `NSWindowController` like this:

```
class MyWindowController: NSWindowController, NSWindowDelegate {

    func windowShouldClose(_ sender: NSWindow) -> Bool {
        NSApp.hide(nil)
        return false
    }
}
```

Then you need just open your Main (or whatever name you have) storyboard, choose `Window Controller` and set your `MyWindowController` to it:

[image]

I tried and it worked for me.

Comment: It hides window but when I click on my app in dock menu it is not opening app again.

Comment: @ViralShah Are you sure you don't have any other code that might block it? I tried my solution one more time and all seems to be working.

Comment: can you please share your demo with me? on viral237@gmail.com

Comment: @ViralShah Sent

Comment: I have found that my main window is working fine. but when I change my window using : {code} let timerVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateController(withIdentifier: "TimerWindow") as! NSWindowController
        self.view.window?.close()
        timerVC.showWindow(self) {code} it is not working.

Comment: @ViralShah Then you need to setup `MyWindowsController` class for your `TimerWindow` controller.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187912/discussion-between-viral-shah-and-silvester).